# Moving JavaScript from mark-up to separate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Javascript/html code looks like following which works great and shows country name in `Part 1` below.

When i am trying to convert the `code in .JS file` it doesnt work means doesnt shows the country name in `Part 2`.. not sure what is wrong in the code

**Part 1**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var strip, strcountry, strcity, strregion, strlatitude, strlongitude, strtimezone
function GetUserInfo(data) {
strip = data.host; strcountry = data.countryName; 
}

$(function ()
{
BindUserInfo();
})

function BindUserInfo()
{
document.getElementById('lblCountry').innerHTML = strcountry;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo"></script>
</head>
<body>

We Ship To <a id="lblCountry"/>
</body>
```

**Part 2**

```
// JavaScript Document

document.write("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");

var strip, strcountry, strcity, strregion, strlatitude, strlongitude, strtimezone
function GetUserInfo(data) {
strip = data.host; strcountry = data.countryName; 
}

$(function ()
{
BindUserInfo();
})

function BindUserInfo()
{
document.getElementById('lblCountry').innerHTML = strcountry;
}

document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo'></script>");
```

**Here is the HTML of PArt 2**

```
<head>
<title>Get User Details IP Address, city, country, state, latitude, longitude </title>
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

We Ship To <a id="lblCountry"/>

</table>
```

Comment: `document.write` is a horrible remnant of the early days of _JavaScript_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the jQuery reference as a *real* script tag in your HTML still - and remove the `document.write`.

Also `;` on the end of your `var` list... Perhaps.

Your `<head>` tag should be

```
<head>
  <title>Get User Details IP Address, city, country, state, latitude, longitude
    </title>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js' type='text/javascript'>
    </script>
  <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

As Paul notes `document.write` is deprecated. You should always try to include `<script>`  tags rather than manipulating the DOM. I *think* that the way you were doing it would mean that the jQuery code in your file would be executing before jQuery had loaded - due to the fact that you are writing the tag directly to the DOM immediately before your code. So there will not have been time to parse it. I would think that this code would have raised an error in fact.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that document.write writes at the end of the body, meaning that jQuery is added at the end, so it won't be parsed until all the other scripts have been parsed & executed.

You could avoid this inserting the script tag _before_ your test.js, but as others have pointed, try to avoid document.write.

Comment: @JuanGuerrero I think even if it wrote at the start of the body then it would not be parsed immediately would it? Meaning that the `$(function()..` call would fail...

Comment: @ElRonnoco yeah, even if he would write it in the head, it would be still parsed AFTER the current script, render my point invalid. Good catch!

Comment: @JuanGuerrero Your point isn't invalid it's just that doing things this way is fundamentally flawed :)